# SQL Perform multi record, mult column addition to return a single number

Tags: sql

I just wondered if someone could help me with an SQL query for a football predictions program I have running..I want to add up and return the current `total` score for each user in my database ..as you can see from my example below, on each week, every user gets a score and a bonus ...I have 2 userIDs in the example below (65 and 52) ...I have included 3 weeks of predictions for each user ...Looking at the first user (65) ..over the 3 weeks he has had scores of 8,7 and 8  ..plus attained 1 bonus point over those 3 weeks ...so i want to find a query that will add this all up for a particular user ..in the case of userID 65, the returned value would be `24` (8+7+8+1 ). ...Ive been struggling to work out how best to get this working ...any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

```
userid,weekid,score,bonus
65, 1, 8, 0
65, 2, 7, 0
65, 3, 8, 1
...
52, 1, 9, 0
52, 2, 7, 1
52, 3, 8, 1
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Ive been trying things like this with no joy so far. ..........


SELECT userid, 
SUM (score + bonus) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY userid;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is good:

```
select userid, sum(score + bonus) from t group by userid;
```

Result:

```
userid  sum(score + bonus) 
------- ------------------ 
52      26                 
65      24
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJXb3aT6h3omPeoEGbnkKy/0).